# Applying inline styles with browser prefixes

Tags: jquery

I found a little trick that allows me to use jquery to add styles to a class with vendor prefixes:

```
 var myTransform = ($.browser.webkit)  ? '-webkit-transform' :
                       ($.browser.mozilla) ? '-moz-transform' : 
                       ($.browser.msie)    ? '-ms-transform' :
                       ($.browser.opera)   ? '-o-transform' : 'transform';

var myCSSObj = {};

    myCSSObj[myTransform] = 'translate('+centrepos+'px, 0px)';
        $("div.current").css(myCSSObj);
```

I'm not entirely sure how this works, so if someone could explain I would be really appreciative.

But, my question is about applying this method and adding it to an inline style to a jquery fragment. Currently I have the following, but it is manually written:

```
$fragment = $('<div class="preload" style="position: relative; -webkit-transform: translate('+start+'px, 0px);"/>');
```

I want to give this container an initial position when it is appended to the dom. How can I add the code without having to manually add each browser's prefix?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly you want to automate the process of adding vendor-specific prefixed to your css properties.

there is an API included in jquery core that allows you to do this. [jQuery.cssHooks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/)

In the documentations there is a nice example about doing similar think for `border-radius`.

Answer (score 0):

See this jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/molokoloco/f6Z3D/

Comment: That's similar to what I did, however what I want to do is do it for inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out lea verou's prefix-free: http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/

> -prefix-free lets you use only unprefixed CSS properties everywhere. It works behind the scenes, adding the current browser’s prefix to any CSS code, only when it’s needed.